# jquery php variable if statement

Tags: php, jquery, variables

Ive been messing around with this for the past few hours and sometimes it seems to work and sometimes it does not. I feel like my syntax could be off a little bit but cant seem to find it. Any help would be great.

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(e) {
       var pick1 = <?php echo json_encode($variable[1]) ; ?>;
       if( pick1 = 'all'  )
 { 
    $("#west tr:eq(1)").hide();

     }
     else 
     { 
     $("#west tr:eq(1)").show();

     }
     });
      </script>
```

my problem is that I am using the php variable and the variable is equal to 'all' but it is not hiding what I want it to hide. Thanks for any help.

Comment: use == for equal check

Comment: As this one can be tricky to find, a good way to write an expression is `if ('all' == pick)` as this will result in an ReferenceError if you use a single `=`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if( pick1 = 'all'  )` will assign 'all' to `pick1`, not check for equality. In this case it will be type-coerced into true, since it is a nonempty string.

To check the value rather than set it, use `==` (type coerced in javascript) or better `===` which does not coerce type.

Comment: "is an assignment, so it will always be true." -- this statement isn't clear enough, assignment expression isn't always true

Answer (score 0):

```
if( pick1 == 'all'  )
```

Change = in == for read the condition (then the boolean value of it)